# Is it possible to add all derived objects from a base class to an array using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have

```
class Foo
{

}

class Foo_Child : Foo
{

}

class FooBar : Foo
{

}
```

In C++, I would create a Vector somewhere outside and have to individually add in the inherited classes. I've recently started learning C# and linq, and am wondering if it is possible for something like:

Go through assembly, if class is inherited from foo, add it into list

as opposed to adding them in one by one. If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved using Reflection.

> Go through assembly, if class is inherited from foo, add it into list

```
// First get the assembly
// In this example we load the currently executing assembly but
// you can load any assembly you would need
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// Then you could use the GetTypes method to get all types from
// this assembly and then filter with LINQ
List<Type> derived = assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t != typeof(Foo)) // we don't want Foo itself
    .Where(t => typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(t)) // we want all types that are assignable to Foo
    .ToList();

// at this stage derived will contain the Foo_Child and FooBar types
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just out of curiosity, do you know of any good sites to read up on how to use linq? MSDN usually complicates things too much for me.